# Object Required Error in already opened Web Page on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation

When i Tried to get the document elements of already opened web page i am getting object required error. i tired the following

```
set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate("....")
ie.Document.GetElementsByID("....").click  'leads to new web page.
```

its like pop up from javascript  so i cant able to access the document elements of this page directly ( i can't use navigate because it like filling form with external details in separate form).so i tired the following to get the elements of page by getting already window opened method by using these

```
Set objIE = GetIE("Location Details")
    ...

    Function GetIE(Title)
      Dim objShell, objIE
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      For Each objIE In objShell.Windows
        If InStr(objIE.LocationName, Title) > 0 Then
          Set GetIE = objIE
          Exit Function
        End If
      Next
    End Function
```

When I use this GetIE function , I am Getting Run Time Error on

```
set objIE = GetIE("Location Details")
```

line like Object Required for GetIE, Please Help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A Set assignment like `Set x = y` will throw an "Object required"
   error, if y isn't an object.
2. A function that returns an object in case of success, should return `Nothing` for failures; otherwise the Set assigment will crash.
3. Non-trival function returns should be checked.

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Function f1(bObj)
  If bObj Then
     Set f1 = New RegExp
  End If
End Function

Function f2(bObj)
  If bObj Then
     Set f2 = New RegExp
  Else
     Set f2 = Nothing
  End If
End Function

Dim bObj, sFnc, oObj
For Each bObj In Array(True, False)
    For Each sFnc In Split("f1 f2")
        WScript.StdOut.Write sFnc & "(" & bObj & ") => "
       On Error Resume Next
        Set oObj = GetRef(sFnc)(bObj)
        If Err.Number Then
           WScript.Echo TypeName(GetRef(sFnc)(bObj)), Err.Description
        Else
           WScript.Echo TypeName(oObj), "ok"
        End If
       On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    Set oObj = f2(bObj)
    If oObj Is Nothing Then
       WScript.Echo "oObj Is Nothing =>", "Object not aquired"
    Else
       WScript.Echo "Got an object"
    End If
Next
```

Output:

```
cscript 25346586.vbs
f1(True) => IRegExp2 ok
f2(True) => IRegExp2 ok
Got an object
f1(False) => Empty Object required
f2(False) => Nothing ok
oObj Is Nothing => Object not aquired
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer horner.